# Can't load image in react-native

Tags: react-native, android-studio

I am a little bit confused because I just want to insert an Image in my Code and my Android Studio is trying to find an index file.

Here is the code I am using to import an image:

```js
return (
  <View>
    {/*Image*/}
    <Image
      style={styles.image}
      source={require("../../assets/images/motor_scooter.png")}
    />
  </View>
);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Syntax Error
None of these file exist
*motor_scooter.png
*src\assets\images\motor_scooter.png\index(.native|.anroid.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.json|
.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
```

I can't figure out why it wants an index. Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Please make sure you're getting the image from the right path.

Comment: you are passing wrong image path `motor_scooter.png`  does not exists 
 in `../../assets/images/motor_scooter.png`.

Comment: are you sure? Here is a picture of my directory:

https://ibb.co/x2547bg

Comment: Can you show your whole setup and from where in the folderstructur the code is getting called from?

Comment: Here is the whole structure with the code and the error massage as screenshot:

https://ibb.co/qFpN6Ns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem the "underscore" made a problem. I just renamed it to "motorscooter.png" and it worked